# how to divide the 3 equal parts li in html

Tags: html, css

Hi in the below code how to divide the space to all the list of iteams and it should be center.
except the Home how to divide 3 equal parts

expected output:
Home          |    About     |      Service

```css
    #section ul {
     width: 1050px;
     margin: 1px auto 0 auto;
     height: 50px;
     padding: 0;
     float: relative;
     border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
     background-color: #556B2F;
    }

    #section ul li {
     position: relative;
     list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
    }

    #section li:before {
     content: " | ";
    }

    #section li:first-child:before {
        content: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="section">
     <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: are you just wanting the links centred or do you want them equal widths too?  if just centred, then I would remove `float:relative`(relative is not a valid value for float)  from the ul and add `text-align:center` otherwise I would go with Paulie's solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `display:table` & `display:table-cell` to stretch the list-items to equal width.

```css
#section ul {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 1px auto 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  /* float:relative*/
  /* NO Such Property */
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  //background-color:#556B2F;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}
#section ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table-cell;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#section ul li a {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="section">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Service</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how to make the text to little bit down

Comment: Updated to vertical align.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your CSS, change `float` from `relative` to `left`:

```
#section ul{
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 1px auto 0 auto;
    height:50px;
    padding:0;
    float: left; // change this, or simply remove because of `display: inline;` for `#section ul li`
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color:#556B2F;
}
```

Comment: should just remove the float - there is no need for it

Comment: yes, can be removed because of `display: inline;` for `#section ul li`